# Passing multiple and multi type parameter to iBATIS

Tags: java, ibatis

I am in a complex situation here. I need to pass three parameter to iBATIS select and 2 of them are `String` and 1 is `List` .

List Looks like:

```
List<User> userList=new List<User>();

public class User
{
   private String name;
   private String location;
   //and other fields and setter/getter 
}
```

Query will look like:

```
Select * FROM myTable Where 
fromDate>= 'date1' and toDate<='date2' and name In ('nm1','nm2','nm3',......) and
location in('loc1','loc1','loc1',.....);
```

**My Progress:**

I have tried by separating the query

**Part 1 (Passing more than one parameter using Map ) :**

```
Select * FROM myTable Where 
fromDate>= 'date1' and toDate<='date2'
```

**Map:**

```
Map<String,String> paramMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
    paramMap.put("fromDate", fromDate);
    paramMap.put("toDate", toDate);
```

**iBATIS query:**

```
<select id="" parameterClass="map" resultMap="">
    Select * FROM myTable Where fromDate>= #fromDate# and toDate<=#toDate#
</select>
```

**Part 2 (only the one part name/location. Passing List and iterate over it):**

```
Select * FROM myTable Where 
name In ('nm1','nm2','nm3,......)
```

**My List (just a String List):**

```
List<String> nameList=new ArrayList<String>();
    nameList.add("nm1");
    nameList.add("nm2");
    nameList.add("nm3");
```

**iBATIS query:**

```
<select id="" parameterClass="list" resultMap="">
SELECT * from myTable WHERE name IN 
    <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction=","  >
    #[]#
    </iterate>
```

These are OK.

**I need to pass those three parameter `fromDate`,`toDate` and `userList` to the iBATIS and access them
to build a query that works like first query I mentioned.**

First of all is it possible ? 
If yes then even a little hint (technique/ process/ link) will save me.

If not then some other suggestions will be appreciated

**Please kindly consider only iBATIS not MyBatis**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still i couldn't find way to directly pass parameter using `List` or `Map` . But i got what i want through the **way:**

I added another Class `Inof` which will be carry the parameters to iBATIS.

```
Public Class Inof
{
    private String fromDate;
    private String fromDate;
    private List<User> list;

}

<select id="" parameterClass="myPackage.Inof" resultMap="">
    SELECT * from myTable WHERE  fromDate>= #fromDate# and toDate<=#toDate# and name IN 
     <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction="," property="list"  >
     #list[].name#
    </iterate>
     and location  IN 
     <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction="," property="list"  >
     #list[].location#
    </iterate>
</select>
```

This give me what i want, but i am not totally satisfied. If still there is some other way which is good practice or efficient  please share.